# How to get info() displayed when my Pandas dataframe has many columns?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, info

I have a Pandas dataframe with many columns (100+) I find it difficult to get detailed information about the columns data types using the .info() method from my Jupyter Notebook:

```
data_grp.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 545466 entries, 0 to 545465
Columns: 111 entries, sku_id to promo_start_day
dtypes: category(23), float64(85), int64(3)
memory usage: 382.4 MB
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Are you after `data_grp.dtypes` perhaps?

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!